# Layout is jumbled in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a simple login form in which there is an image and two buttons:
[image: flutter]

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smart_shop/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:smart_shop/screens/signup.dart';

class LoginSignup extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = "LoginSignup";

  @override
  _LoginSignupState createState() => _LoginSignupState();
}

class _LoginSignupState extends State<LoginSignup> {
  List<Widget> _screens = [Login(), Signup()];
  int _screenNo = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [

              Image.asset("images/Group 22.png"),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _screenNo = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign up",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20
                        ),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                            width: 3
                          )
                        )
                      ),
                    )
                  ),

                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                        "Login",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20
                        ),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                              bottom: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                                  width: 3
                              )
                          )
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              _screens[_screenNo]
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Login:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Signup:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Signup extends StatefulWidget {
  const Signup({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupState createState() => _SignupState();
}

class _SignupState extends State<Signup> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but whenever I try to run the app I get this UI:
[image: flutter_error]

I am getting the following error:

```
RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
```

Even if I add any children to the column widget in login and signup, I am getting the same error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Try setting up `mainAxisSize: MainAxizSize.min` to the `Column`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming from  `_screens[_screenNo]`, you already have `SingleChildScrollView` for parent on `_LoginSignupState`, you don't need to wrap another `SingleChildScrollView` and `Scaffold` on `_screens` items.

Remove `Scaffold` and `SingleChildScrollView` from `_SignupState` and `_LoginState` widget.

```dart
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [],
    );
  }
}
```

And

```dart
class Signup extends StatefulWidget {
  const Signup({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupState createState() => _SignupState();
}

class _SignupState extends State<Signup> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error could be caused by your widget structure.

The first part of the widget tree is ok, but when you call `_screens[_screenNo]` you are nesting the `Login` or the `Signup` widget within your tree.

The resulting tree will have 2 Scaffold and SingleChildScrollView, that's not good.

Since you are already inside a Scaffold and a ScrollView I would rewrite `Login` and `Signup` widget as this:

```
class Signup extends StatefulWidget {
  const Signup({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupState createState() => _SignupState();
}

class _SignupState extends State<Signup> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children:[]
    );
  }
}
```